# if statement in loop not working

Tags: python

For the life of me I can't figure out why my IF statement is not getting hit. There are plenty of cases where the remainder of n // the last number put in the results list is 0.

```
n = 100
numbers = range(2, n)
results = []


results.append(numbers.pop(0))

print numbers

for n in numbers:
    if n % results[-1] == 0:
        print "If statement", numbers
        numbers.remove(n)
    else:
        print "Else statement", numbers
        numbers.remove(n)
```

Comment: Try adding debugging output just after the for and just after the if, e.g. `print n` `print results[-1]`

Comment: You are removing items from `numbers` while iterating over it. That will lead to bugs as the iterator counter will increment regardless and your loop will 'skip' items.

Comment: Calling `list.remove` causes a *side effect* on the list - what oddities may (does) this cause here? I would rewrite this *without* using remove - the opposite of removing things, is keeping those which should be kept :D It also seems odd to remove in both branches (= remove everything), but ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you're modifying the list while iterating over it, so all the even numbers are getting skipped. Hence the `if` condition is always `False`.

The `for` loop keeps track of index, so when you remove an item at index `i`, the next item at `i+1`th position shifts to the current index(`i`) and hence in the next iteration you'll actually pick the `i+2`th item.

```
for n in numbers[:]:   #iterate over a shallow copy of list
    if n % results[-1] == 0:
        print "If statement", numbers
        numbers.remove(n)
    else:
        print "Else statement", numbers
        numbers.remove(n)
```

Example:

```
>>> lis  = range(3,15)
>>> for x in lis:
...     print x
...     lis.remove(x)
...     
3
5
7
9
11
13
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't loop over a list you are removing items from. The `for` loop creates a list iterator that keeps track of the current item by incrementing a counter. But a shrinking list means that the counter will, from loop iteration to loop iteration, point at the wrong item:

```
>>> lst = range(5)
>>> for i in lst:
...     lst.remove(i)
...     print i
... 
0
2
4
>>> lst
[1, 3]
```

What happens is that as you remove `0` from the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, the counter increments to item `1`, which in the now-altered list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` points to the value `2`. Removing `2` from the list, the iterator count increments to `2` and in the altered list `[1, 3, 4]` that means the next value in the loop is `4`, after which the iterator counter has counted beyond the end and the loop terminates.

If you are going to remove *all* items from the list, use a while loop:

```
while numbers:
    n = numbers.pop()
    # do something with `n`
```

If you are removing *some* items, another option would be to create a shallow copy:

```
for n in numbers[:]:
     # ....
```

Now you can alter `numbers` to your hearts content, as the `for` loop is iterating over a copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of list modification is doing two passes:

```
mod0 = []
for n in numbers:
    mod0.append(n % results[-1] == 0)
print [ n for n,m in zip(numbers, mod0) if m ]
print [ n for n,m in zip(numbers, mod0) if not m ]
```

Comment: It seems quite useful to have a built-in method for doing it. I needed something like that many times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as others answered, is the modification of the list you are iterating on. I think what you really tried to do can be done like this:

```
results = [2]
numbers = []

n=100
for n in range(3, n):
    if n % results[-1] == 0:
        results.append(n)
    else:
        numbers.append(n)
```

which is a way to get powers of two. another way would be:

```
results = [2**n for n in range(1,7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a list while looping over it, meet my little friend the [while statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

```
numbers=range(1,20)
while numbers:
    if numbers[-1] % 2:
        print "If statement", numbers.pop()
    else:
        print "Else statement", numbers.pop()
```